# Prove that the set of all text of finite length denoted $S$ is countably infinite.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that the union of countably infinite sets is countably infinite so that is where I was hoping to go with this proof. I would denote the set S which is the set of all text of finite length and represent it as being the union of multiple sets. I would denote it as the union of the countably infinite set $A$ which is all texts that begin with the letter $A$ unioned with set $B$ which is all texts that begin with the letter $B$ and so forth until I reach $Z$. So it would look like $S = A\cup B \cup C\cup D\cup E\cup F\cup G\cup\dots\cup Z$. Since I know that each of these countably infinite would that prove that $S$ must therefore be countably infinite?

Comment: (i) You need a *countable* union of countable sets to be sure of countability (ii) Why do you believe that the set of all text  beginning with A is countable? - it's pretty clearly in 1-1 correspondence with the set of all taxt.

Comment: I believe that the set of all text beginning with A is countably infinite since I can put it in alphabetical order and count it that way. A = 1 AA=2 AB=3 AC=4 AD=5.. onto infinity. Since there are 26 letters in the alphabet wouldnt that be a countable union since there are 26 of these sets?

Comment: You have only dealt with text of length 1 and 2 here, what about longer text. Where does $AABZA$ go on your list?

Comment: It would be the 476556th entry on the list. It is ordered alphabetically so you go from AA to AZ then you go to AAA then AAZ then ABA